# VS Code deploying takes too long

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, vs-code

Deploying any updates via VS Code salesforce extension can take 5-10 minutes. Restarting of VS code helps for 2-3 first deploys and then the issue comes back.

Deployment Status at org says, that deployment finished successfully, but VS Code still shows the "Running SFDX: Deploy Source to Org" notification.

Reinstalling SFDX-CLI and VS Code doesn't help.

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a bug on salesforce github repo: [Deploy Source to org command takes several minutes to complete](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4865).

For now the workaround is to downgrade SFDX CLI extension in vscode to a lower recommended version: `v57.10.2`.

Use `Install Another Version` option as per screenshot below:
[image]

---

My prefered option is to disable [salesforce's deploy on save](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/user-guide/deploy-on-save) use CLI directly but manually running deploy command everytime is little tedious.

To automate this, I like to use [Save and Run](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wk-j.save-and-run) vscode extension, using which I configure custom deploy on save command with below setting in `.vscode/settings.json` file on my workspace:

```json
{
    "saveAndRun": {
        "commands": [
            {
                "match": "force-app/*",
                "isAsync": true,
                "cmd": "time sf project deploy start --source-dir '${file}' --ignore-conflicts"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Note: I run SF retrieve before working on a file, hence I ignore conflicts with `--ignore-conflicts` flag, discard it if you want to see conflicts with save.

Comment: I have set up a ctrl+alt+d to deploy. Its muscle memory now like blinking and takes about the same time. Better than usual manual deploy.

Answer (score 1):

check what do you have in
setup / apex settings / Perform Synchronous Compile on Deploy

we had this issue when this setting was set to true, deployment of any apex class would take 3-5 min

Answer (score 1):

For me, disabling this setting in vs code did the job.

```
{
   "salesforcedx-vscode-core.experimental.enableSourceTrackingForDeployAndRetrieve": false
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks this helped me out!