# VS Code CLI Retrieve taking too long to respond/complete

Tags: vs-code, performance, git, cli, retrieve

For several years I have been using the SF CLI retrieve commands in VS Code to retrieve data from my Partial Copy Sandboxes to my local git repo.
About a month ago I moved from using the `force:source:retrieve` commands to the `project retrieve start` commands.
Over the last few weeks I had seen occasional delays when trying to retrieve a single component. Usually by the time I would start to troubleshoot the delay would resolve and not return for the rest of the day.

Since the beginning of this week it is been taking over 5 minutes to retrieve a single component - the request just hangs on `Preparing retrieve request... ⣾ Pending`

I have tried the following and received the same results...

1. Confirmed *Perform Synchronous Compile on Deploy* is disabled
   under Apex settings in my Partial SBX Orgs
2. Disabled  *Enable Source Tracking For Deploy And Retrieve* in SF Core Cofig in VS Code
3. Downgraded to an older version of CLI
4. Deleted VS Code sfdx.log file.
5. Used the legacy `force:source:retrieve` commands
6. Retrive via manifest.xml

This is happening across multiple Sandbox Orgs and impacting me and my colleague. Any help in troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated

Configuration

- VS Code 1.84.2
- M1 MacBook Pro Ventura - 13.6 (22G120)

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***
Rolling back Salesforce Extension Pack to v57.10.2 [as described here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/404637/vs-code-deploying-takes-too-long) worked for me.

Experiencing the same problem retrieving metadata.  Did a complete uninstall, shut the machine down,  reinstall and same issues.  Seems like it will work somewhat decent on the very first retrieve after a shut down but too slow after that.  Not annoying slow, productivity killer slow like I need to find a new IDE . Deploy is still always snappy.

Mac Silicon Ventura 13.5
VSCode 1.84.2
@salesforce/cli/2.17.14 darwin-arm64 node-v20.9.0

Comment: I saw that post and tried downgrading.  At the time this did not help. I have since re-upgraded.
Over the last few weeks I have not experienced delays.